# Effect of inflation on stock market

Tags: stocks, inflation

What is the effect of inflation on stock market activity? Not the effect of inflation to the returns on a particular stock (some stocks may fare well in case of inflation, other stocks may fare badly I guess), but the effect of inflation on stock market investor sentiment. Do people start selling, do they start buying, or do they hold or just stay away?

Comment: Keep in mind that inflation is the measure of increase in the cost of things (including stocks). So generally the stock market is a hedge against inflation because as other prices go up, stock prices also tend to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stocks are regarded as an inflation hedge because when your money is worth less, everything else is worth more. i.e. Stocks are more expensive (go up) simply because your money is worth less, but not because of better earnings across individual companies.

So that general idea can effect sentiment, whereby if everyone believes it then more people buy stocks if they think there will be a lot of inflation. But it doesn't explain actual behavior (whether "more" people buy, hold or sell.)

It's worth noting that individual companies and stocks also may be adversely affected by inflation, since their own assets or accounting may already be outside of the currency and/or they may already be engaging in their own hedging.